# Identify double byte character in a string and convert that into a single byte character

Tags: go, double-byte

In my Go project, I am dealing with asian languages and There are double byte characters. In my case, I have a string which contains two words and there is a space between them.

EG: こんにちは　世界

Now I need to check if that space is a double byte space and if so, I need to convert that into single byte space.

I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find a way to do this. Since I cannot figure out a way to do this, sorry I have no code sample to add here.

Do I need to loop through each character and pick the double byte space using its code and replace? What is the code I should use to identify double byte space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main()  {
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace("こんにちは　世界", "　", " ", -1))
}
```

Notice that the second argument in `Replace` is 　, as copy-paste from your string in example. This replace function will find all rune that match that in the original string and replace it with ASCII space

Comment: This does not catch double byte spaces. It returns the same thing since it does not find that one. And double byte space and single byte space look similar to the eye. it is not two spaces as i know

Comment: @vigamage, strings.Replace doesn't care what it replaces. It doesn't "catch" anything. It just replaces one byte sequence with another. As long as you use the particular space you're interested in as the second argument this will just work.

Comment: I was thinking of much complex scenarios like converting it into a rune and then check each char. Dumb me didnt think of this simple solution. The reason for my comment on your answer was not seeing the first space as a bigger one(a double byte one). I saw that as a usual space

Answer (score 2):

In golang there is nothing like double byte character. There is special type `rune` which is `int32` under hood and rune is unicode representation.

your special space is `12288` and normal space is `32` unicode.

To iterate over characters you can use range

```
for _, char := range chars {...} // char is rune type
```

To replace this character you can use `strings.Replace` or `strings.Map` and define function for replacement of unwanted characters.

```
func converter(r rune) rune {
    if r == 12288 {
        return 32
    }
    return r
}
result := strings.Map(converter, "こんにちは　世界")
```

It is also posible to use characters literals instead of numbers

```
if r == '　' {
    return ' '
}
```